# MySQL is not connecting with server

Tags: windows-10, command-line, mysql, services, localhost

I am currently using MySQL 8.0.36 on Windows 10. Today, when I started my computer to work on SQL, I encountered an issue where it displayed 'No connection established.' Subsequently, I attempted to modify settings through the 'services' menu, but the option to start the service was not visible, indicating that it was not running.

In an effort to resolve the problem, I uninstalled MySQL from the control panel and proceeded to reinstall it. However, during the installation, certain steps were not displayed. Upon completion of the installation, I reopened MySQL only to encounter the same error once again.

For a clearer understanding of the issue, I have attached photos depicting the error messages and steps taken. Any assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn’t appear the service is installed. Your image doesn’t provide enough diagnostic information to help identify the reason that might be the case. I suspect a configuration issue that is preventing the service from starting and/or in fact not actually installed

Comment: A Win32 exit code of 1077 essentially means “No attempts to start the service have been made since the last boot”. I would fix your missing error log issue. I would reinstall MySQL in it’s entirely, starting from scratch, only potentially keeping the database after the service is running

Comment: The path to executable doesn’t seem correct, mysqld is a binary, so unless your database name is “MySQL” that doesn’t appear to be correct. What is clear is that the service cannot be started.l and not attempt to start the service (1077) has been made

Comment: I would also look to make sure any depenencies are running.  That is also a reason the ability to start a service from the GUI would be grayed out. It's also a reason the service would be stopped.

Comment: I reinstalled MySQL from scratch and it worked smoothly. Thankyou for your help